# What WPF features are useful in non UI applications

Tags: wpf

WPF has many new features ,pattern and concepts. Some online text suggests that some of  these features can be used in other types of application as well.Specially WindowsBase.dll provides many of these features. Is this true? If yes , then I would like to ask what are these features that can be directly consumed in non UI applications? Any experience shared on the same will be really helpful. I am really new to WPF and sorry if this question do not make any sense.Thanks for kind help.

Comment: I think your question is a bit too vague to be properly answered here. "Some online text suggests" -- can you provide links or excerpts as to the referenced features? Then we can at least have a basis from which to address the question of non-UI usefulness.

Comment: At this moment I can find this link http://www.wpf-training-guide.com/wpf-assemblies.html

Comment: one more [link](http://allcomputers.us/windows_xp/windows-presentation-foundation-in-_net-4---introducing-wpf---the-architecture-of-wpf.aspx)

Comment: This just makes no sense.  WindowBase.dll is Windows Presentation Foundation Base Library and yet you are asking how to use it in a non UI application?  You do know WPF is a UI and .NET is a Framework?  Specifically what are you trying to do?

Comment: [This](http://www.wpf-training-guide.com/wpf-assemblies.html) link clearly mentions that majority of types from WindowsBase.dll can be consumed in other types of applications. I know that WPF is UI framework , there may be classes originally designed for WPF, but that can be pe useful in non UI apps as well. I am interested to know if any one has experience on that. Its not important for me in which dll they are present. I am more interested in reuse of code.Say for example Dependency properties are more memmory efficient and provides changed notifications and validation. Is'nt it reusable?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one thing you have the observable data structures like `ObservableCollection` (although in .NET 4 it was moved to system.dll). Those can be useful also in non-UI scenarios - having a background service which updates a collection and then having one or more components watching for the changes and reacting to them for example (writing things to a database, pushing data to a webservice etc.). The whole reactive framework is build around observable patterns.

Comment: That may be what Prafulla meant to ask but that was not the question.   The question was how to use WindowsBase.dll (WPF) not .NET.

Comment: @Blam: He was asking about concepts and patterns as well not just about WindowsBase. And `ObservableCollection` lives in WindowsBase (or at least used to depending on which version of the Framework you use)

Comment: OK, but now there is a more clear separation of UI and .NET and "WPF new features" does imply latest version.  I do think you did answer the intended question.  +1

Comment: Ya this is what i am interested in. I am hoping for few more answers.